# Как правильно делать миграцию? magicalrecord relationship mapping migration

Tags: objective-c, coredata, model

При миграции на новую версию *.xcdatamodeld, что указывать в relationship mapping?

Натыкался на вот такую формулировку:

```
FUNCTION($manager, "destinationInstancesForEntityMappingNamed:sourceInstances:" , "dialogToDialogs", $source.d)
```

но ничего не выходит.
http://joxi.ru/ZrJNjPKf1nk18r